# One membership for each user for each club

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating models to manage clients and sports centers. Each customer can be enrolled in several centers only once of course. how should i proceed for this?

```py
class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='memberships')
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    sub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    #other...
```

If I proceed in this way it is possible to create multiple subscriptions of the user to the same club. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unique_together` in the model Meta so that a Membership object cannot have the same user *and* club as another object:

```py
class Membership(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'club']
```

This will return an error if you use a form or the Django admin to create a membership that already exists with that user/club.

Answer (score 0):

Use [m2m relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

```
field = models.ManyToManyField(Your_model)
```

Comment: That doesn't stop a user having multiple memberships to the same club